# How create a validation field from model that's not in the database table? With MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, validation, model

I’m trying to create a validation field for a model that I don’t have in the table of the database. But I get this error "The column name 'editPassword' is not valid.”

Here’s my code from the model…

```
private string _editPassword = "0";
        [LocalizedDisplayName("UserPassword", NameResourceType = typeof(Languages.Names))]
        [StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinimumStringLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Languages.Validations))]
        public virtual string editPassword { get { return _editPassword; } set { _editPassword = value; } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute to your Property.

Answer (score 1):

You would do well to create a separate View Model and use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to map between your database entities and the View model instead of trying to use database entities directly in the view.